# MVVM - Efficiently pass fetched data from network requests in parent view to child views using SwiftUI & Combine

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, combine

I am building my first app as I learn SwiftUI and the Combine framework, so I am sorry if this question regarding MVVM is somewhat basic, but I am really stuck right now.

I built a `SomeWebService` class that returns multiple publishers to consume different resources of a Web API that powers my app:

```
class SomeWebService {
    func resourceA() -> AnyPublisher<ResponseA, SomeWebServiceError> { ... }
    func resourceB() -> AnyPublisher<ResponseB, SomeWebServiceError> { ... }
    // etc...
}
```

The responses are potentially large structs that I would like to fetch only once in a `ParentView` and then pass them in the most efficient way to child views that can use a combination of those resources to display processed data. I just don't know how to efficiently pass those resources to the children and initialise their view models with these resources.

I first created a `Fetcher`:

```
class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var resourceA: ResponseA? // Potentially large struct
    @Published private(set) var resourceB: ResponseB? // Potentially large struct
    // etc...
    
    private let webService = SomeWebService()
    
    private var cancellableA: AnyCancellable?
    private var cancellableB: AnyCancellable?
    // etc...
    
    func fetchA() {
        cancellableA = webService.resourceA()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error): print(error)
                case .finished: break
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                self?.resourceA = response
            })
    }
    func fetchB() { ... }
    // etc...
}
```

Then I wanted to use it in the `ParentView` to perform all network requests only once `onAppear`, or whenever the user wants to refresh the app:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject private var fetcher = Fetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildA() // view model needs a combination of resourceA, resourceB, etc
            ChildB() // view model needs another combination of resources
            // etc ...
        }
        .onAppear {
            fetcher.fetchA()
            fetcher.fetchB()
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Right now each child view has its own view model where I fetch the combination of resources that that particular child view needs, so I am currently fetching and storing unnecessary copies of those resources.

1. I would like to use the resources as parameters to the children view models, so that I can handle all the data processing logic inside each of those view models. Is this a bad ideia?
2. If I can go that route, how should I pass those potentially large responses to the children view models?

Comment: What does "Potentially large struct" mean? Tens of megabytes? Hundreds? Do the child views use them as @State values or do they just consume them?

Comment: @jnpdx The responses can be tens of megabytes each. The child views, don't mutate the responses, just consume them. Each child uses (many) different properties of the responses which then need processing before being presented. I was doing that in computed properties of each child view model.

Comment: I'd pass them as parameters and then use instruments to see if you're actually getting memory increase because of copies getting made. My suspicion is that because they'll be immutable values in the child views that the compiler may optimize out actually "copying" the values, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks I will try that! However, I still don't quite get the whole picture. The responses need different processing before presenting each child view. I had that logic in the children view models which were `StateObject`s that fetched those resources too. Now I am passing the response/data source (model?) directly to the children view, but I still need to process the responses. Shouldn't I do that in a child view model? How can I inject the responses on those view models once the parent fetches the resources from the network?